# Purpose of "client_x509_cert_url" field in JSON file generated by Google Oauth 2.0 Provider

Tags: google-openid

When we create a new "Client ID" on Google developers console and select the Application Type as "Web", we get the option to download a JSON file that includes a lot of key-value pairs. This JSON file is for the consumption of the Open-ID web client during the setup phase.

One of the key value pairs I see is "client_x509_cert_url: 
https://www.googleapis.com/robo/v1/metadata/x509/......".

When I copy paste the above URL in a browser I see an empty JSON response {}.  I suppose the intent here is to let an OPEN-ID connect client to populate the public cert of a public-private RSA key pair for signing and encrypting JWT request objects.  But I do not see any documentation on how to upload a client certificate in the Google developers console.

Is this because Google does not support JWT request objects yet?

Answer (score 1):

client_x509_cert_url is the URL of the public x509 certificate, used to verify JWTs signed by the client.

i think for a web application, it use the oauth2.0 authorization code flow, which does not need to sign the JWT, actually it does not use the JWT at all.

But if you create a service account, https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

and the downloaded json file will include a client_x509_cert_url, which that url does work and will display the public key of the certificate.

Than's because the service account uses the oauth 2.0 [JWT Bearer Token flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7523), which client has to use private key to sign.

Comment: How to decode the contents of payload located at client_x509_cert_url ?